# Spivak Calculus 3rd. Edition Chapter 1 Problem 12 (v) and (vi) Proofs Critique

Tags: inequality, absolute-value, formal-proofs

Here are my "proofs" for Spivak's Calculus Chapter 1 Problem 12. I am new to this level of rigour and I am attempting to intimate myself with more advanced topics of mathematics to prepare for next year. I apologize in advance, as these so-called "proofs" are not likely to be nearly as rigorous as they should be. Any assistance on how to write the proofs better or any critiques on faulty logic would be greatly appreciated.

12) *v*) Prove that $|x|-|y|\leq|x-y|$ (A very short proof is possible if you write it the right way.)

(This is where I start feeling especially uncomfortable with my answers.)
My proof is:

By (*iv*), $|x-y|+|y|\geq|(x-y)+y|$

$\therefore$

$|x-y|+|y|\geq|x|$, and $|x|-|y|\leq|x-y|$, which is what we wished to prove.

12) *vi*) Prove that $|(|x|-|y|)|\leq|x-y|$ (Why does this follow immediately from (*v*)?)

My proof is:

$|(|x|-|y|)|\leq|x-y|$ has two primary cases, $|x|-|y|\leq|x-y|$ and $-(|x|-|y|)=|y|-|x|\leq|x-y|$

The first case follows immediately from (*v*), and the second case follows when $x$ and $y$ are switched in (*v*). ($|x-y|=|y-x|$).

12) *vi*) Prove $|x+y+z|\leq|x|+|y|+|z|$ and indicate when equality holds.

My proof is:

$|x+y+z|=|x-(-y-z)|$, which by (*iv*)$\leq|x|+|-y-z|=|x|+|y+z|$

$\therefore$

$|x|+|y+z|=|x|+|y-(-z)|\leq|x|+|y|+|-z|=|x|+|y|+|z|$, which is what we wished to prove.

By (*iv*), equality holds when $|x|+|y|=|x+y|$, which is when $x$ and $y$ have the same sign. By extension $|x+y+z|=|x|+|y|+|z|$ when $z$ has the same sign as $x$ and $y$. (With the exception of the cases where one variable equals zero.)

Comment: In the first problem, you start by stating that $|x|-|y| \leq |x-y|$, but this is what you are trying to prove!

Comment: You are correct sir. I'll edit that and see what you have to say.

Comment: (iv) and (v) look good now. For (vi), your proof of the inequality is fine, although I wonder why you chose to use $|x+y+z| = |x-(-y-z)|$ instead of simply $|x+y+z| = |x+(y+z)|$ and applying the triangle inequality to that. But your way is perfectly valid. You didn't really answer the last part, when does **equality** hold? Meaning, when is $|x+y+z| = |x|+|y|+|z|$?

Comment: I wasn't aware that it applied to $|x+y|$ as Spivak only has me proving $|x-y|\geq|x|+|y|$. I might have to prove that in another exercise. Also, I'm not sure I really understand how to show that equality holds. I assumed it was the same as a domain, a set of certain values for which the equation is correct.

Comment: $|x+y| \leq |x| + |y|$ is proved in Theorem 1 in Chapter 1, at least in my edition (4th). Believe it or not, although it is quite simple, this is one of the most important inequalities in rigorous calculus/real analysis! Note also that following the proof of Theorem 1, Spivak has a discussion regarding when equality holds, which should be helpful.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to save up for a hard copy and I am using a .pdf of the 3rd. edition, which makes it much more difficult to look back at the chapter. I appreciate the comments. You have been most helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These all look great! It doesn't look like you need to stick in the minus signs on $y$ and $z$ at the beginning of vi), though.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure how specific to be, so I tried to be as painfully detailed as possible. I'll take that into consideration next time I write a proof.